# Input File field text styling not applying

Tags: html, css, file, symfony, input

I'm trying to style my file input text element. 
It should look like this:
[image]

But currently with the code below the appearance is like this:

[image]

I have no idea how I can style the text itself, only the button is getting padding..

I'm also struggling with explaining the problem, I hope the screenshots are clear.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.marketing__block {
  padding-bottom: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marketing__block h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'BrandonTextBlack';
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.marketing__row {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="file"] {
  border: 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

input[type="file"] {
  padding: 15px;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #595959;
}

textarea {
  border: 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #efc506;
  color: #efc506;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'BrandonTextBlack';
  padding: 12px 36px;
  background: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="marketing__block">
  <h4>Solliciteer online</h4>

  <form name="job_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_firstName" name="job_form[firstName]" required="required" placeholder="Voornaam *">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_name" name="job_form[name]" required="required" placeholder="Naam *">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="email" id="job_form_email" name="job_form[email]" required="required" placeholder="Email *">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_tel" name="job_form[tel]" placeholder="Telefoon Nr.">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_url" name="job_form[url]" placeholder="Url">
      </div>


      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="file" id="job_form_attachment" name="job_form[attachment]" placeholder="form.label.attachment">
      </div>


      <div class="marketing__row">
        <textarea id="job_form_message" name="job_form[message]" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea>
      </div>




      <div><button type="submit" id="job_form_submit" name="job_form[submit]" class="button">Verstuur</button></div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" id="job_form_type" name="job_form[type]" value="form_job_application"><input type="hidden" id="job_form__token" name="job_form[_token]" value="">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Input file is different than other input types. You cannot change it directly from css. What you should do is that.

```
<div>
  <element you will style>
  <label for="file-input">a label</label>
  <input type="file" id="file-input">
</div>
```

wrap it between a div. Then change input and label opacity to 0 and make it absolute and all left,top etc. = 0. What it does is that it makes your input and label invisible so even user thinks that he is clicking on the text displayed s/he actually clicks on input label or button.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the file input and set label style to match your design.

```css
.marketing__block {
  padding-bottom: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marketing__block h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'BrandonTextBlack';
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

fieldset {
  min-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.marketing__row {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="file"],
.filelabel {
  border: 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

input[type="file"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity:0
}

.filelabel {
  display:block;
  color: #595959;
  height:42px;
  line-height:42px;
}

input,
select,
textarea,
.filelabel {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #595959;
}

textarea {
  border: 0;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  resize: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #efc506;
  color: #efc506;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'BrandonTextBlack';
  padding: 12px 36px;
  background: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="marketing__block">
  <h4>Solliciteer online</h4>

  <form name="job_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_firstName" name="job_form[firstName]" required="required" placeholder="Voornaam *">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_name" name="job_form[name]" required="required" placeholder="Naam *">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="email" id="job_form_email" name="job_form[email]" required="required" placeholder="Email *">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_tel" name="job_form[tel]" placeholder="Telefoon Nr.">
      </div>

      <div class="marketing__row">
        <input type="text" id="job_form_url" name="job_form[url]" placeholder="Url">
      </div>


      <div class="marketing__row">
        <label for="job_form_attachment" class="filelabel">Label</label>
        <input type="file" id="job_form_attachment" name="job_form[attachment]" placeholder="form.label.attachment">
      </div>


      <div class="marketing__row">
        <textarea id="job_form_message" name="job_form[message]" placeholder="Bericht"></textarea>
      </div>




      <div><button type="submit" id="job_form_submit" name="job_form[submit]" class="button">Verstuur</button></div>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" id="job_form_type" name="job_form[type]" value="form_job_application"><input type="hidden" id="job_form__token" name="job_form[_token]" value="">
  </form>
</div>
```